# Is there a canonical corrupted, opposite, or otherwise chaotic Modron?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore

In *any* published edition of D&D or D&D fiction, is there lore for a modron that has somehow been corrupted by chaos?  A "fallen" modron, akin to fallen angels?  Or a creature *similar* to a modron, except opposite to it?

I know as a DM I can simply make something up, just checking to see if there's anything even remotely official first.

Answer (score 20):

Modrons can and do go rogue, often as a result of spending too much time alone, attempting to reconcile too many conflicting orders, or from exposure to Chaos.

While rogue, they retain all their powers, including their command over lower-ranked modrons, but are no longer subject to orders from higher-ranked modrons.

On death, they return to the energy pool on Regulus to be reborn as a (non-rogue) monodrone, the same as any other modron. This gives them a sort of mortality.

Rogue Modrons first appear in the AD&D1e *Monster Manual II*, are developed across the AD&D2e Planescape setting (notably in the *Planes of Law: Mechanus* supplement), and one named Nordom is a recruitable character in the computer game *Planescape: Torment*. Rules for playable rogue modrons first appeared in *Dragon* magazine, issue #235.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that rogue modrons ususally are still lawful in alignment; they're just not as perfectly lawful as non-rogue modrons tend to be. They might even (gasp) *make mistakes filling out the form used to apply for rogue modron status!*